# Looking for option for 3-way file sync

Tags: sync, privacy, cloud

I want to be able to have a 3-way sync for some files between home and work PCs and my Android (HTC Sensation, 2.3).  I want to sync a few documents and Keepass password database.

What options are there for this?  I found [SMEStorage](http://www.smestorage.com/?p=static&page=Android) which looks very good, but I can't really see a good sync provider that does everything I need:

- Windows Live Mesh: good for transparent sync on the PC, but I did read somewhere that docs synced from here would be [read-only](http://www.smestorage.com/?p=static&page=about#SkyDrive) on Android (this doesn't apply to Skydrive, but can you sync to that like you can with Live Mesh?)
- DropBox - hmm, I really don't want all my files publicly readable thank you...
- FTP - I'd have to have a separate sync solution on my PCs
- Google docs - not good on PC as I want a physical copy synced one each one.

Is there some other simple method I'm missing?  If there was a way of getting it to work with Live Mesh then that would be ideal.

EDIT:
  Looks like Live Mesh also syncs to Sky Drive, so Android clients that have read/write sync to Sky Drive may work, such as [Sorami](https://market.android.com/details?id=shoozhoo.sorami&feature=search_result) or SMEStorage may work

Comment: DropBox (with the exception of your "Public" folder) is completely secure...

`Other Dropbox users can't see your private files in Dropbox unless you deliberately invite them or put them in your Public folder. Everything in your Public folder is, by definition, accessible to anyone.`

https://www.dropbox.com/help/27

Comment: Completely secure apart from this: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/06/21/dropbox_security_issue/

Comment: it was only unsecure for four hours.

Comment: @the_mandrill: security fuckups like this can happen to any provider, including if you had your own FTP server (well, especially if you owned your own server). I don't think this knee-jerk reaction is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SMEStorage. I actually use 2 Storage Clouds on it. My home WebDav Server and SkyDrive.

My files physically reside on my home WebDAV server and on SkyDrive. I have a phone to SkyDrive folder sync setup through the SMEStorage App for some docs/files.

SMEStorage has the ability to encrypt files uploaded to it and then decrypt on the fly from the  Client, which suits me. It uses AES-256 and does not store the private key so if you lose the key your stuffed but again this approach suits me.

Comment: Thanks. I did go for SMEStorage before I saw your response. It looked to be the most versatile option that seems to cater for every platform and storage mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own private folders to Dropbox, you don't have to use the `Public` folder. I use this for some syncs between work, home and phone.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm concerned about Dropbox's security - see above comment

Comment: @the_mandrill you could always encrypt the files yourself that you put on Dropbox

Comment: I could, but then that defeats the idea of having transparent client sync at each end as that necessitates having to decrypt, edit and then re-encrypt

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sugarsync](https://www.sugarsync.com/).  Similar to Dropbox but without the poor security track record.  The Android client also handles automatic sync where dropbox doesn't.  Of course the Windows clients do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs actually would be a viable solution. You just need a way to sync local files to and from GDocs.

[ReadWriteWeb reviewed three such apps](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/3_tools_to_sync_your_files_with_google_docs.php). There are surely others.

Answer (score 0):

i am using aerosync to sync a folder over various devices , it works well and it's free and unlimited storage on any number of device but no cloud storage , it's having client for all platform